# How to parse a JSON string in Android?

Tags: android, json

The following JSON string comes to me after a request. Whatever I try, I can not parse the data.

```
[{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5909846cbd966f2d371bc624"
    },
    "member_id": "NTkwOTEyNzdiZDk2NmYyZDM3MTkyY2M1",
    "sensor_name": "Temprature",
    "value": "27.28",
    "date": "2017-05-03 10:19:07"
}]
```

Comment: Are you parsing it in Android?

Comment: "Whatever I try"... What have you tried?

Comment: yes it is android

Comment: @stealthjong all get methods volley and logcat ...

Comment: Pro-tips for posting: (1) include all the details about the problem, including what language and operating system you're using. (2) Include an attempt or what research you have done to solve your problem, and (3) choose a succinct title that describes the issue, omitting chatty and begging material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using following code :

```
try {

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.get(0);

    JSONObject _id = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_id");
    String old = _id.getString("$oid");

    String member_id = jsonObject.getString("member_id");
    String sensor_name = jsonObject.getString("sensor_name");
    String value = jsonObject.getString("value");
   String date = jsonObject.getString("date");

}catch(JSONException e){
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved my problem. no rep because my reputation :(